# Sorting a hand of cards in C++ poker

Tags: c++, sorting

I am working on a homework assignment that involves creating a simplified poker game. I am new to C++, but this is for class, so I am here to learn.

After I deal each players hand vector, how would I sort the vector before it prints? They are char vectors called `hand1` for player 1, and `hand2` for player 2. The deck is a vector of chars as well, but the rank array is a string (so that the number `10` prints), and the suit array is a char (so that the actual symbols print). Instead of printing: `8<heart>, 3<club>, A<spade>, 4<spade>, 9 <diamond>, 8<club>, 2<club>,` it would print: `2<club>, 3<club>, 4<spade>, 8<heart>, 8<club>, 9 <diamond>, A<spade>.`

I hope this was enough information. I can send my code if you'd like to look at it. No pointers, no classes. I'm not at that level yet (unless there is no other way to do what I am asking). I can improve upon this project in my next class.

Comment: I've seen a symbol T used in card games instead of 10, if you really need one symbol per number.

Answer (score 4):

How about std::sort.

It sorts a vector.

```
std::sort(hand.begin(), hand.end());
```

See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html

Answer (score 3):

use `std::sort`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to create a `struct` for each card:

```
struct card {
   char textRepresentation; // 2, 3, A, J
   int  color; // any code..

   int  sortOrder; // a number describing the position in a sorted order
   // you can also include the color here somehow
};
```

Then you can easily sort those cards..